# Why doesn't this comparison approach work in Ruby

Tags: ruby

Let's say I have array

```
s = ['Armando','P']
p s[1] ==  ('R' || 'P' || 'S')
```

I though that would return true since P is included in the "OR" comparison but it returns false

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/26765267/128421 for a breakdown of what the logic is doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in that the expression `'R' || 'P' || 'S'` evaluates to 'R' (because it's the first truthy value in the expression. Obviously `'P' != 'R'`, that is why the complete expression evaluates to `false`. What I would do is use a regular expression instead:

```
# Revised regexp according to Cary Swoveland's recommendation:
!!s[1][/\A[RPS]\z/]  #=> true
```

Comment: That would be to convert a truthy/falsey value to either `true` or `false`. They are not really needed, but without them `s[1] =~ /\A[RPS]\z/ #=> 0`. If you want to transform the zero to `true` or `nil` to `false` you can prefix the expression with `!!` (performing a [boolean negation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/BasicObject.html#method-i-21) twice).

Answer (score 2):

Because that's not how it works. The definition of `A || B` is `A` if `A` is truthy, `B` otherwise. The evaluation order is as in mathematics, parentheses go first; so `('R' || 'P' || 'S')` is `'R'` (because at least the first of them is truthy; in fact all of them are). Then `'P' == 'R'` is obviously false.

You need to write it as:

```
s[1] == 'R' || s[1] == 'P' || s[1] == 'S'
```

Shorter alternative:

```
%w(R P S).include?(s[1])
```

Comment: If that's within an `if` statement, you could also write `case s[i]; when 'R', 'P', 'S'; then....; else...; end`.